# How to properly use '{}'.format() while finding an element with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syntax

I am writing a functions that searches inside a website using a name_parameter, but I am sure I am misspelling something and I cannot get the correct button with my input. I know the XPATH has the correct structure because if I hard code the page_name then I get the expected result

```
def change_user(self, page_name):
    select_user = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 4).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((
                    By.XPATH, f'//div/div/div/span[contains(text(), {0} )]'.format(page_name)))
            )
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.15, 0.5))
    select_user.click()
```

A hard coded actually working version of this function is the following:

```
def change_user(self, page_name):
        select_user = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 4).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((
                        By.XPATH, f'//div/div/div/span[contains(text(), "Carl Rogers" )]'))
                )
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.15, 0.5))
        select_user.click()
```

I am using this reference for the syntax https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```py
path = r'//div/div/div/span[contains(text(), "{}" )]'.format('test')
```

Comment: This one worked great! I did a small addition to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `f"String {variable}"` or `"String {0}".format(variable)` but you are using both. Just remove the `f` at the start of your string.